# Windows move very slowly (<1 FPS) until I kill dwm.exe

Tags: windows-7, dwm

Occasionally, when turning on my external monitors for my docked laptop after being docked overnight, Windows will perform very slowly.  Turning on my monitors means the screen resolution changes which usually happens before the monitors turn on, but in these cases I can still see the old resolution for 10 seconds or so until everything in pops back in place all at once.

- Clicking on a window takes 1-4 seconds for it to react.
- Minimizing a window takes 1-4 seconds.
- Mouse movement is always fluid and never has a problem.
- Software seems to work fast... it just doesn't display that way.
- CPU usage across the board is ~1%.
- Temperatures are fine.
- If I open task manager and kill dwm.exe, **immediately** the problem is resolved (as it restarts).
- Using another session (such as for a UAC prompt) works smoothly, and when returned to my session things are slow again.

dwm.exe doesn't seem to be using any CPU at all and hardly any memory.  What's going on?

### xperf.exe Results

After running xperf as suggested by @magicandre1981, here are the results:

[image]

On GPU utilization, you can see the small triangles.  Each one of those is when my frame updates, so it happens every 2 to 4 seconds.  At 30 seconds in, I start task manager, which is what that CPU spike is.  At 55 seconds, I kill DWM causing all the indicated delays in the highlighted area of the graph.  After that, I browse some web pages in Chrome smoothly without problem.

CPU Usage:

[image]

Is there anything else I should be checking out in this report?

Comment: You can try looking at your event logs and see if anything is suspicious. If you see errors for video card drivers or dwm.exe directly then you can try re-installing your drivers. Read this for more info on dwm.exe http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-dwmexe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks.  I'm using the latest video drivers, and have had this problem on 3 different versions of drivers over the last year.  (Intel HD 4600 with NVIDIA GeForce GT730M attached.)  I also use DisplayFusion, but I've had this problem long before I installed it.  In my event viewer, DisplayFusion has logged two PowerEvents.  My computer was not suspended, shutdown, or rebooted overnight so I'm guessing that PowerEvent was some sort of internal power saving feature and maybe that's messing up dwm.exe.

Comment: You need to eliminate any possible explanation other than a driver problem.  So something like `DisplayFusion` for the time being should be removed out of the equation until the cause ( which `DisplayFusion` might be the cause ) can be located.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, I've had this problem for a long time and only just installed Display Fusion. I also tried removing DisplayFusion. It makes no difference either way unfortunately.

Comment: It sounds like you might have something called Nvidia Optimus which is basically a graphics chip switching technology which is supposed to be an energy saving technique. I would recommend completely removing the nvidia drivers and try running only HD 4600 and see if things improve. You can also try this in reverse and disable the HD 4600 completely.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yep, that's the one!  As far as I know, the Nvidia card hasn't fired up at all as I haven't ran any games or anything, nor Photoshop.  But, I suppose it's possible that some piece of software has used it.  I will try disabling it and see how it goes.  Unfortunately, this only happens on average once every couple weeks.  (Sometimes it will happen every day in a row for a week though.)  So, it may take a couple months to definitively answer.

Comment: capture th slowness via xperf: http://pastebin.com/9m5kkYAj and share the captured trace. Maybe I can see anything from it.

Comment: It is hard to tell, obviously the docking adds another layer of complexity to the existing technologies so I hope that you eventually get this thing figured out. Good luck!

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, I have to catch it in the act again.  It doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Trace captured.  It doesn't look very helpful though.  I've looked through it and posted some of the highlights.  Let me know if you see anything suspicious that I can look at.  If you need the full report, please provide your e-mail address as I would rather not post it for anyone and everyone on the internet.  Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: yeah, the trace was not that helpful. But the last weeks several suers reported perf issues, when they use Chrome. They fixed it by disabling the HW acceleration inside Chrome. Also try if this fixes it for you

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it.  I've had this issue since I bought my laptop over a year ago, but I have always used Chrome.

Comment: any updates on this? Where you able to fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I disabled hardware acceleration and the issue hasn't happened again, but it can sometimes take weeks to occur so I'm waiting to see.

Comment: ok, let's hope that this fixed it for you.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately, the problem has occurred again with Chrome hardware acceleration disabled.